# Error creating bean with name 'tilesViewResolver'

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tiles

i am trying to run my app using tilesViewResolver. and run output will print hello form tiles in default.jsp file.
but is not running show some error.

error like

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'tilesViewResolver': Lookup method resolution
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   introspect Class
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver] from
>   ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader

servler.xml

```
        <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
             class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/layout/default.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

default.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

    <tiles-definitions>
        <definition name="index" template="WEB-INF/templates/default.jsp"> 
        </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

default.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 hello from tiles.
</body>
</html>
```

file

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

add jar

```
tiles-extras 3.0.5
tiles-servlet 3.0.5
tiles-jsp 3.0.5
slf4j-simple 1.7.6
```

Comment: anyone plz help me

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: i am using java version  8

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace in your questions?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesViewResolver': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader

Comment: What version of spring are you using?

Comment: i am using spring version 5.0.2

Comment: plz help me anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with jar file. When I added these jar files. Then it works

**jar file:**

```
1. tiles-core-3.0.8
2. tiles-jsp-3.0.8
3. tiles-request-api-1.0.7
4. tiles-request-jsp-1.0.7
5. tiles-request-servlet-1.0.7
6. tiles-servlet-3.0.8
7. tiles-template-3.0.8
8. tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.2
9. tiles-api-3.0.8
10. slf4j-api-1.7.6
11. jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6
12. commons-digester-2.0
13. commons-beanutils-1.8.0
```

This link contains all the jar files

```
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp/3.0.8/source-code
```